# Axiomatizable class of algebraic structures which is not the reduct of a variety

Tags: model-theory

In the signature, (+), the class of groups is an axiomatizable class of algebraic structures which, though not a variety in that particular signature, is the reduct of a variety in the signature (+, 0, -). But does there exist an axiomatizable class of algebraic structures, maybe even finitely axiomatizable, which is not even the reduct of a variety? By algebraic structure, I mean one without relation symbols, only functions and constants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class of fields has this property, since the product of two fields is not a field.

Or, take the class of algebras (in a given language) of size exactly thirteen (this is indeed axiomatizable by a single first-order sentence).

Comment: So, you are saying reducts of varieties are closed under products? Where is the proof?

Comment: @user107952 Suppose (for $i\in I$) $A_i$ is the reduct-to-$L$ of the $L'$-algebra $A_i'$. Then the reduct of the product of the $A_i'$s is the product of the reducts of the $A_i'$s - this is a good exercise. Meanwhile, note that an $L$-subalgebra of a reduct need not be a reduct of an $L'$-subalgebra (e.g. the semigroup $\mathbb{N}$ as a subalgebra of the reduct of the group $\mathbb{Z}$ is not the reduct of a group), and similarly for homomorphic images.